# What can WebMatrix do that Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 beta as an IDE can't?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webmatrix

I am seeing a lot of blog posts lately about WebMatrix. I don't read them because I tell myself "I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with SP1 beta". The king of IDE's.

Just in case I am not missing on something important, as an IDE, is there anything that WebMatrix can do that VS 2010 can't do or does better?

Comment: From http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx it looks like WebMatrix has better publishing support. Not sure if you'd include that in the IDE experience though.

Answer (score 1):

Presently:

- Access to the Application Gallery which I think is quite a nice feature. I like the way I can grab dasBlog or WordPress, do some edits and miscellaneous fiddling around, test then squirt the app up to the server. I think that's a killer feature for both beginners and experienced devs.
- There's also task orientated site starter templates that Visual Studio 2010 lacks
- Simplicity - with Visual Studio 2010 there's a lot going on in the UI, all sorts of "technical looking" project types. WebMatrix has one project type which is web projects.

Comment: Thanks. However not really stuff inside the IDE as in the code editor or any designer VS is lacking.

Comment: @tony - WebMatrix is an IDE, these are features of it's IDE. If you meant just a subset of the IDE then you should more clear.

Comment: @Kev - I think the term Web Project is a little ambitious. It's no more than a Web Site.

Comment: @Mike - Perhaps but if you want to you can still put a lot of functionality in App_Code. I work as a developer for a web hoster writing all sorts of "serious" systems - provisioning, billing, payment processing code, control panels etc...so no it's not exactly something that's going to set my day job on fire. But....I'll be using it to knock out my BlogEngine blog revamp because it's effortless to use. Also as a hoster it's a godsend because we'll finally start seeing the last of FPSE which is a friggin security and admin 'mare. I think it's a fun bit of software.

Comment: @Kev - Absolutely agree with you. There's also nothing to stop you dropping dlls into a bin folder (you have to manually add one first....) and taking advantage of all sorts of external libraries.

Comment: I am more interested in the IDE core functionality than peripheral stuff. As in creating my own app from scratch and being disconnected from the net.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been using VS 2010 or even VWD 2010 and haven't been confused by them so far, you are not missing out on anything. WebMatrix is not intended for you. It has been designed to attract beginner developers, or those who know a little PHP or perhaps classic ASP and would like to try out ASP.NET.

It is primarily designed to make developing Razor Web Pages sites easy, with no clutter. No code complete, no Intellisense (well... except for the wrong kind of HTML Intellisense), no debugging, no compilation required (or possible), no wizards. Bare bones. Knuckle deep in HTML tags and inline code...

Actually, if you are anything like me, you are missing out on a lot of fun ;o)

Comment: Well.. I see blogs from known bloggers and I am pretty sure they are hard core VS developers and they talk a lot about WebMatrix. I am going "What's all the fuss about WebMatrix & why are they excited about it?". Made me think maybe I should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that this is not in VS.net, but one thing I use in Webmatrix is the Reports feature that lets you run an analysis against your site to find common issues with the site like SEO and accessibility.  I know this can be done using an IIS7 plugin, but not sure if it can be done directly in VS.net.

The other thing Webmatrix has is a nice interface to IIS Express that allows you to set settings and see requests to your development site in Webmatrix.  VS.net 2010 sp 1 has IIS Express support but I haven't seen as nice an interface there.

Also, not too sure if this is not in vs.net, but when you create an SQL CE 4 database in Webmatrix it has a tool to migrate that database to normal sql server.

Finally, something subjective, Webmatrix has a simplicity to it that vs.net does not.  VS.net is built for a developer to do anything and everything.  It has a gazillion menus and options plus extentions, dockable windows and at least 4 distinct versions.  Webmatrix is built just to create web sites.  That simplicity lets you go from point A to Z very fast even if you don't know much about setting up web sites, databases or asp.net.  It's one IDE where you know that every feature in it is expressly meant for you to create a web site.